# What is the purpose of a UML Qualifier?

Tags: uml, qualifiers

I can't understand what a qualifier is in UML. 
For example, in the scanned page, there's a qualifier named
"SharedRegister" that has "state" and "plateNumber" in it.

Why not just used a class called SharerRegister and put "state"
and "plateNumber" in it? What does it offer over a class exactly?

[image: Schaum UML - pg 108]

(Image from Schaum's Outlines, UML 2nd edition. Simon Benett. Pg 108)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`state` and `PlateNumber` act like a key with which the related class can be accessed. If you didn't use a qualifier you would have a relation between the classes with multiplicity of * but would not know exactly how they are related. Here, you know that class `ShareRegister`, by knowing a specific value for `state` and `PlateNumber` can access 0 or 1 instances of `CarSharer`.